# Validating required selection in DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, validation

My view model defines property which has to be displayed as combo box. Property definition is:

```
[Required]
public int Processor { get; set; }
```

I'm using `DropDownListFor` to render combo box:

```
<%=Html.DropDownListFor(r => r.Processor, Model.Processors, Model.Processor)%>
```

`Model.Processors` contains `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` with one special item defined as:

```
var noSelection = new SelectListItem
  {
    Text = String.Empty,
    Value = "0"
  };
```

Now I need to add validation to my combo box so that user must select different value then 'noSelection'. I hoped for some configuration of `RequiredAttribute` but it doesn't have default value setting.

Comment: If the user is not supposed to select the "noSelection" why have you added it to the list of options?

Comment: To force him to make selection.

Comment: If you ony want a blank as the initial option, use the overload of Html.DropDownListFor that takes a string as the prompt value: Html.DropDownListFor(r => r.Processor, Model.Processors, Model.Processor, String.Empty)   then the required validation should work

Answer (score 26, accepted):

How about this:

```
[Required]
public int? Processor { get; set; }
```

And then:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.Processor, Model.Processors, "-- select processor --"
) %>
```

And in your POST action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // the model is valid => you can safely use model.Processor.Value here:
        int processor = model.Processor.Value;
        // TODO: do something with this value
    }
    ...
}
```

And now you no longer need to manually add the `noSelection` item. Just use the proper [DropDownListFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703561.aspx) overload.

Comment: Nice, I completely misunderstood that overload. Thanks.

Comment: This does not validate on client side :(

Comment: This works for me ... perfect. So, instead of adding the default value directly to the model, you add it directly via the overload.

Comment: This worked for me too, but trying to figure out why? Any reason why this works and the other doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue is that jQuery Validate does [run any rules if the value of an element is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14759805/1366033).

You can get around this by [retriggering the validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12195091/1366033) when the user loses focus:

```js
// select statements not firing null validation automatically
$("select").blur(function () { $(this).valid() });
```