# Adding the 'required' attribute with DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, razor

I have this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, new SelectList(Model.SomeList, "Value", "Text"))
```

And would like it to be rendered as this:

```
<select required>
    <option>...</option>
    ...
```

How would I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validating required selection in DropDownList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672289/validating-required-selection-in-dropdownlist)

Comment: are you setting the value as `[Required]` on the model?

Comment: Side note, http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_required.asp, according to w3c it isn't supported yet.

Comment: @RômuloSpier `[Required]` isn't a valid keyword apparently. Do I have to put any `using` statements or etc for it to work?

Comment: @idlackage, yes you should add `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;`

Comment: The Required attribute won't achieve the element you're looking for. @TimS. this isn't a duplicate of that question, it's new functionality in HTML 5.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, new SelectList(Model.SomeList, "Value", "Text"), new {required = "required"})
```

It won't achieve the shorthand `<select required` but it should have the same effect. Although I've found you could achieve that exact element using

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, new SelectList(Model.SomeList, "Value", "Text"), new {required = (string)null})
```

Which is a little ugly.

Comment: `new {required = String.Empty}` might do it as well - I'm about to try it :)

Comment: `new { required = default(string) }` generates the shorthand `<select ... required>`

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(Model) Model.ProgramTypeId, New SelectList(Model.allPrograms, 
"ProgramTypeId", "ProgramName"), "Select Program....", 
New With {Key .class = "form-control", Key .required = "Required"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
@Html.DropDownList("PlanType", null, "Select Plan Type", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", required = "Select Plan Type" })
```